What does being "informed of the appropriate safeguards pursuant to Article 46" mean?
Article 15 of the GDPR the Right of access includes section 2:

Where personal data are transferred to a third country or to an international organisation, the data subject shall have the right to be informed of the appropriate safeguards pursuant to Article 46 relating to the transfer

Article 46 Transfers subject to appropriate safeguards has a very long list, much of which the meaning is not obvious to me.  What does this mean in practice?  Is this a large amount of detailed information, or the sort of general terms that one finds in for example the AXA privacy policy which says (page 41):

Where we make a transfer of your personal information outside the United Kingdom in all cases where personal data is transferred to a country which is deemed not to have the same standards of protection for personal data as the UK AXA will ensure appropriate safeguards such as UK regulator approved Standard Contractual Clauses and further contractual, organisational and technical measures (as may be required following an assessment of the risk) have been implemented to ensure that your personal information is protected.

Is this sufficient to cover the requirements for a data subjects right to be informed under article 15.2 if the data transfer is made under Article 46, say to the US to an organisation not on the Data Privacy Framework List of organisations approved for data transfers under the UK Extension to the EU-US Data Privacy Framework?
Note I have asked a separate question about if these rules apply to an Article 45 transfer.
